# print formatted numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, formatting

I want to print formatted numpy array along with a float with different significant figures. Consider the following code

```
a = 3.14159
X = np.array([1.123, 4.456, 7.789])
print('a = %4.3f, X = %3.2f' % (a, X))
------------------------
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

I desire following output-

```
a = 3.141, X = [1.12, 4.45, 7.78]
```

Suggest a modification in the code.

Comment: you can't apply scalar `%f` formating to a whole array.  As with a list you have to iterate, applying it element by element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert array to string first with [`array2string`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array2string.html):

```
print('a = %4.3f, X = %s' % (a, np.array2string(X, precision=2)))
# a = 3.142, X = [1.12 4.46 7.79]
```

Comment: this doesn't have the commas as indicated in the question.

Comment: @SOFe `np.array2string(X, precision=2, separator=',')` would give you the commas. See the `separator` option in https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array2string.html.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `np.set_printoptions(precision=2)`:

```
import numpy as np
a = 3.14159
X = np.array([1.123, 4.456, 7.789])
np.set_printoptions(precision=2)
print(f'{a = :4.3f}, X = {X}')
```

Output

```
a = 3.142, X = [1.12 4.46 7.79]
```