# how do I show decimal point in print function in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to find the roots of an equation and I need to print the roots with 10 decimal points I used the following code but it produced an error. how can I tell python to print 10 decimal points?

```
def find_root(a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,a2,b2,c2,d2,e2,f2):
    coeff=[a1-a2,b1-b2,c1-c2,d1-d2,e1-e2,f1-f2]
    print('%.10f' %np.roots(coeff))

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Maedeh\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_14412\3234902339.py", line 1, in <cell line: 1>
    find_root(0.0024373075,-0.0587498671,0.4937598857,-1.7415327555,3.6624839316,20.8771496554,0.0021396943,-0.0504345999,0.4152634229,-1.4715228738,3.3049020821,20.8406692002)

  File "C:\Users\Maedeh\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_14412\3260022606.py", line 3, in find_root
    print('%.10f' %np.roots(coeff))

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Comment: Potentially relevant:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68639461/print-formatted-numpy-array .

Comment: What's wrong with `print(roots(coeff))`?  `%.10f`%` only works for ONE number, not an array.  `print(roots(coeff).tolist())` should show more decimals, but not as neatly.

Comment: because some numbers are like this -0.57210237+0.j and I am unsure if the coefficient of j is zero or if it is tiny and cannot show. so I need to increase the precision.

Comment: So you have the further complication that the numbers are complex.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[numpy.roots](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roots.html) has no direct parameter to pass while calling function for setting up precision. It will take a array of values and returns array of elements at once. You can set precession on numpy after importing like so.

```
def find_root(a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,a2,b2,c2,d2,e2,f2):
    coeff=[a1-a2,b1-b2,c1-c2,d1-d2,e1-e2,f1-f2]
 
    print(np.roots(coeff))
     

import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(precision=10)
find_root(0.0024373075,-0.0587498671,0.4937598857,-1.7415327555,3.6624839316,20.8771496554,0.0021396943,-0.0504345999,0.4152634229,-1.4715228738,3.3049020821,20.8406692002)
```

which outputs #

```
[11.41569308+2.82260609j 11.41569308-2.82260609j  2.60173681+1.60008454j
  2.60173681-1.60008454j -0.09501304+0.j]
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use [`np.set_printoptions`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html#numpy.set_printoptions). One of the parameters it takes is `precision`.